# how to intercept HTTP request by NSURLProtocol at airplane mode (offline, ios)

Tags: ios, webview, offline, nsurlprotocol

We're trying to cache some H5 pages in device and have used NSURLProtocol to intercept HTTP requests.

At normal network type (wifi / 4G / 3G / 2G) it works well, but failed at airplane mode (or close cell + wifi).

Error occured: -1009.

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: 2017/05/16 problem cannot be reappeared